# how to get staus value from json response using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting the response from webservice this

**{"Message":null,"Status":0,"Result":["AF9E8C84D6491D96570A4DA7981F98DE49785EFE"]}**

from the success now I want to print result and status how I will print this ?

```
success: function (t) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(t));
        alert(JSON.stringify(t))
    },
```

Comment: You can use t.Message, t.Status & t.Result. As undefined pointed out you do not need to stringify if the data is set as JSON in the ajax request. At this end you will receive JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (t) {
        alert(t.Status)//Will alert status
        alert(t.Result)//Will alert Result
        console.log(JSON.stringify(t));
        alert(JSON.stringify(t))
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
success: function (t) {
    var data = JSON.parse(t);
    alert(data['Status']);
},
```